# AWS DeviceFarm ignores TestNG annotations

Tags: amazon-web-services, cucumber, testng, appium, aws-device-farm

I have some Appium TestNG tests used for testing a native iOS and Android app. The tests work fine when running them locally or when submitted to AWS DeviceFarm.

However, in DeviceFarm, the TestNG annotations like @AfterMethod, @BeforeSuite, etc, are completely ignored.

[This AWS forum resource](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=747413) says that for Calabash, hooks are ignored. I cannot find anything specific to Appium Cucumber.

*I cannot post any code yet unfortunately.*

Is there some way to have DeviceFarm honour those annotations?

Comment: Have you tried running your tests in AWS Device Farm's [custom environment mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html)?

Comment: I have, yes. It turns out DeviceFarm does actually honour the annotations. So this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tobe mentioned, AWS Device Farm only supports TestNG annotations in its "custom environment" mode of execution.

Comment: I was running in custom environment. I realised later that it was working.